# php SOAP not sending certificate.pem

Tags: php, security, soap, pem

I can load in the wsdl, pull out the functions and data types just fine but when I try to call a function on the server I get a connection error. When I look at the soap data passed in the $request it doesn't contain any of the security certificate and no errors are generated.

My code looks like this:

```
  // setup the transaction array
  $header = array('local_cert' => "certificate.pem",
                  'logonUser'  => "user_name",
                  'style'      => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                  'use'        => SOAP_LITERAL,
                  'exceptions' => true,
                  'trace'      => true);                  

  // create the soap client, this will log us in
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $header);

  try
  { 
    $response = $client->getMessage($parameters);
  }
  catch (Exception $e) 
  {
    dumpVars($client->__getLastRequest()); 
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
  }
?>
```

So my question is this, what do I have to do to get the security certificate to be passed?

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Here is the xml being sent to the server:

Comment: [code]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
      xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:ns1="http://domain.com/soap_request" 
      xmlns:ns2="http://domain.com/soap_request/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:getMessageTypeDef>
        <ns1:requestAPI>API_TYPE1</ns1:requestAPI>
        <ns1:requestOperation>getMessageByDate</ns1:requestOperation>
        </ns2:getMessageTypeDef>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>[/code]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of local_cert in $header is not sending it in the SOAP call itself. It's only being used as an SSL client certificate. Also, according to [this comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#104751) you need to read the file contents of the certificate in order to use it.

Comment: Yeah, bottom line is that php doesn't support ws-security in its soap client so I'll probably find another tool to do this job with.

Answer (score 0):

2 (small) things :

- 'logonUser' does not seem to be a valid option for the [SoapClient constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapclient.php). If it is a required header for this service, consider using [soapClient::setSoapHeaders](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php). If it is a standard HTTP login param, use the 'login' key.
- try to use the full path of the pem certificate, and make sure it is readable by php

Comment: What I think I'm learning about this is that anything you pass in the array just gets used during the constructor and anything else, like you said, has to be done in soapheaders.  The second part is that php doesnt support wsse so another tool is requrired.